# Exclude hue-variable from legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, legend, scatter-plot

I struggle finding a way of properly displaying only the labels respective to the markers in a scatterplot. My code looks as follows:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
plot_white = sns.scatterplot(data=df_white, x='EngCorr_Player', y='EngCorr_Opponent', hue='Elo_Opponent', ax=ax, marker='D', label='White')
plot_black = sns.scatterplot(data=df_black, x='EngCorr_Player', y='EngCorr_Opponent', hue='Elo_Opponent', ax=ax, marker='X', s=140, label='Black')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

The problem here, is that the variable for the hue is included in the legend. [Plot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3iZT.png)

If I instead try to specify the labels when calling the legend, the marker of the second plot is wrong (circle, instead of star). [Plot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEkKM.png)

```
ax.legend(labels=['White', 'Black'])
```

And if I specify the handles, with

```
ax.legend(handles=[plot_white, plot_black], labels=['White', 'Black'])
```

An empty legend is displayed and the error message *"UserWarning: Legend does not support <AxesSubplot:xlabel='EngCorr_Player', ylabel='EngCorr_Opponent'> instances.
A proxy artist may be used instead."* appears.

I tried to look into artists but don't grasp anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this what you are looking for... It is similar to what you have. Except that you get the handles and text of the legend using `ax.get_legend_handles_labels()`, then keep only those with names White and Black and then call ax.legend()

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax = sns.scatterplot(data=df_white, x='EngCorr_Player', y='EngCorr_Opponent', hue='Elo_Opponent', ax=ax, marker='D', label='White')
ax = sns.scatterplot(data=df_black, x='EngCorr_Player', y='EngCorr_Opponent', hue='Elo_Opponent', ax=ax, marker='X', s=140, label='Black')
hand, labl = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
handout=[]
lablout=[]
for h,l in zip(hand,labl):
    if l in ['White', 'Black']:
        lablout.append(l)
        handout.append(h)
ax.legend(handout, lablout)
plt.show()
```

[image]